# How to send private message to all users in an IRC channel?

Tags: irc

How to send the same private message to all users in a room in an IRC channel in a rather automated way, that is, not having to do it manually for all users one by one and not having to post the message in the channel room. 
To be used wisely, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.4.1) that describes the IRC protocol, **private messages are technically not different from channel messages**. Both are the result of the `PRIVMSG`
command.

The `PRIVMSG` command allows any client to send messages to several recipients, using the following syntax:

1. `PRIVMSG foo,bar[,anon] :Hi there` for users
2. `PRIVMSG #help,#home[,#irc] :Hi there` for channels
3. That's supposed to work mixed-up as well.

So basically, a single target has to be either a channel or a user.

As far I read, there is no way of doing that, since every target has to be defined in the first *parameter* of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your network. Some networks support wallmsg which works on many IRC clients as  a private message to the user. This is achieved on efnet for example by sending a message to @#channel which then distributes the message to all channel ops. Equally use + to send a message to all voiced users. Unfortunately, this does not work for non-op/voice users. This works by doing `PRIVMSG @#channel :Hi!`

To be able to do that, in an automated fashion, you would need to write a simple script (can't help you there, you haven't stated your client) that loops over all users and then sends a PRIVMSG to them one by one or in the mass message mode where you separate the users by commas (and no spaces) like `PRIVMSG user1,user2,user3 :message`.

Most likely you want the latter option. Be careful with your flood thresholds though!

Answer (score 0):

```
You could add a line to your mirc popups nick list

...message all selected {%i = 0 | %nicks = "" | :nextnick | inc %i | if ($snick(#,%i) == $null) { if ($len(%nicks) > 0) /msg  %nicks $$?="message " | halt } | %nicks = %nicks $snick(#,%i) | if (4 // %i) { /msg  %nicks $$?="message " | %nicks = "" } | goto nextnick | }
```

i use this on my network along with op all and deop all or kick all